# How to cover Catch block for triggerfactory in Test class?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am using `TriggerFramework` for implementing a trigger on case. When I started writing tests for this trigger, this catch statement isn't covered by the tests:

```
trigger CaseMain on Case (before insert, before update, after insert, after update) {
  try {
       TriggerFactory.createAndExecuteHandler(CaseHandler.class);     
  } catch(Exception ex) {
       MilestoneUtils.SendNotificationOnTriggerFailure('CaseMain', ex);
  }
}
```

The rest of the code is executed, but not the catch batch. I tried to insert a record which would throw a SoqlException, NullPointerException, or a DmlException, but none of these covered the code.

Comment: Does your trigger framework itself catch and handle exceptions?

Comment: yes in createAndExecuteHandler it is.only get if it didn't get the handler.

Comment: If all exceptions are being caught and handled or swallowed in `TriggerFactory.createAndExecuteHandler`, no exception will ever reach the `catch` block here, and there's no reason for it to exist.

Comment: so all exception will go here...
public static void createAndExecuteHandler(Type t){
    ITrigger handler = gethandler(t);
    //to check weather handler is exist or not
    if(handler == null){
      throw new TriggerException('handler is not exist' + t.getName());
    }
    execute(handler);
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach that I've taken to solve this problem is to include an `@testVisible`, `private static Boolean forceException`.

The code for that would be placed inside of your trigger factory, and would look like this:

```
public class TriggerFactory{
    @testVisible
    private static forceException = false;

    // Custom exception classes seem to be good practice
    // Doesn't really need to do anything other than extend the standard
    //   exception class
    public TriggerFactoryException extends Exception{}

    public static createAndExecuteHandler(...){
        if(forceException){
            throw new TriggerFactoryException('Forced exception');
        }

        // existing code here

    }
}
```

Then, in a unit test method, you simply set `TriggerFactory.forceException = true;`, et voila, easy, guaranteed exception.

Comment: hi @Derek F with this i didn't get my code in catch block.i want my code in Test class for in catch block for casei simply insert case and Case  c = new Case(Desk_com_Status__c = 'test',Subject = 'test',Status='Open',  SlaStartDate = System.today().addDays(-10)); and then insert c; and TriggerFactory.forceException = true;

Comment: @sonam I'm afraid that your comment does not make any sense. Including code in comments does not work out very well. This (including clarification and an update to your situation) is something better off as an edit to your original question.

Comment: Thank you..now my problem get solved.i got where i was wrong.